# custom Customer attribute value not save while customer register

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I have created test attribute using install script it is successfully created.I have added attribute input field in register.phtml

When I register customer my custom attribute value won't save. Do I need to rewrite any model or create any plugin?

Comment: Please check log. There is some issue with your attribute. That's why u r not able to save.

Comment: no log related to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it. I rewrite controller `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost`

my `di.xml` code as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost" type="Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Account\CreatePost" />
</config>
```

Add below code in controller file code `Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Account\CreatePost.php`

```
$customer->setCustomAttribute('test',$this->getRequest()->getPost('test'));
```

Comment: where you put your code ...which line ?

Answer (score 1):

You should check those fields in your install script:

> 'attribute_set_id' 'attribute_group_id'

They are should be set.

For example:

```
/** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->_customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    /** @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set $attributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->_attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'phone', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Phone Number',
        'input' => 'text',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'sort_order' => 100,
        'position' => 100,
        'system' => 0,
    ]);

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'phone')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create']
        ]);
    $attribute->save();
```

Comment: Good job. It works